# Remove sources after building python

Tags: debian, python3

as there is no apt repository for python 3.8 for Debian, I followed the instructions to build it with make.
After installing it with make install, I asked my self if I can remove the downloaded (or better extracted) sources.

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: You’re in for a world of hurt if you replace the system Python 3 with your own build. Please use virtual environments instead.

Comment: Good point but even with virtual environments I need to build it first, don't I?

Comment: Yes, but I don’t think you need to install it.

Comment: Okay, so I just call make and not make install, but my original question stays the same. Can I delete the sources after building it?

Comment: Can I also use make altinstall to install python 3.8 but not replacing the system Python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to keep the sources because you can always download them again.

Comment: ... but also in the very version used to compile the project?

Comment: ... sure you can, as long as the sources are still available.